# Ordering objects by type before sorting by property

Tags: sorting

I am trying to sort objects in a list by type before sorting them by name using the IComparable interface. It's not a problem to sort by name, but it is (at least for me) difficult to sort by object type. I have three classes Schoen, Shirt and Broek which inherit from an abstract class Artikel. Every object has only name and price properties (inherited from Artikel).

Sorting by name wil result in this:

```
jan 10 (schoen)
clara 20 (broek)
denise 30 (shirt)
karel 40 (broek)
lena 50 (broek)
marie 60 (schoen)
nico 70 (shirt)
otto 80 (shirt)
pauline 90 (schoen)
```

What I'm looking for is this result:

```
jan 10 (schoen)
marie 60 (schoen)
pauline 90 (schoen)
clara 20 (broek)
karel 40 (broek)
lena 50 (broek)
denise 30 (shirt)
nico 70 (shirt)
otto 80 (shirt)
```

I have no idea how to tell the CompareTo in the article class how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction. It's probably something simple I'm overlooking.

Update 18-08:
Code used to test:

```
 public class ArtikelTypeComparer : Comparer<Artikel>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> nameSortOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"schoen", 0 },
        {"broek", 1 },
        {"shirt", 2 },
        {"unknown", int.MaxValue }
    };

    public override int Compare(Artikel x, Artikel y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return 0;
        if (x == null) return -1;
        if (y == null) return 1;

        int xOrder;
        int yOrder;
        if (!nameSortOrder.TryGetValue(x.GetType().Name, out xOrder))
    {
            xOrder = nameSortOrder["unknown"];
        }
        if (!nameSortOrder.TryGetValue(y.GetType().Name, out yOrder))
    {
            yOrder = nameSortOrder["unknown"];
        }

        int rslt = xOrder.CompareTo(yOrder);
        if (rslt != 0)
        {
            return rslt;
        }

        // Types are the same. Compare names.
        return x.Naam.CompareTo(y.Naam);
    }

}
```

And in my form:

```
private void btnSorteer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        app.artikelen.Sort(new ArtikelTypeComparer());
        VerversAlleLijsten();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your CompareTo method?

Comment: Also, if you can use LINQ you could try by doing this: `array.GroupBy(x => x.GetType()).Select(g => g.Value.Sort(... sorting code ...)).SelectMany(x => x)`

Comment: Sure nothing fancy though:                                                                             `public int CompareTo(Artikel other)
        { 
            return Naam.CompareTo(other.Naam); }`

Comment: I *guess* you could do something like this (untested code): 
`public int CompareTo(Artikel other) 
{
    var orderArr = new [] 
    {
        typeof(Schoen), 
        typeof(Broek), 
        typeof(Shirt) 
    };
var otherType = other.GetType();
    var ord = Array.IndexOf(orderArr, otherType);
    if (ord == -1) return 1;
    if (this.GetType() != otherType)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(orderArr, this.GetType()).CompareTo(ord);   
    }
    return Naam.CompareTo(other.Naam); 
}`

Comment: @zdimension: If you're going to post more than a single line of code, please do it in an answer, not a comment. Comment-formatted code makes the eyes bleed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. With LINQ, you want to use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy`. In your case, you want to sort by type first, then by name.

Sorting by type requires a custom comparison. We'll call that `ArtikelTypeComparer`. Sorting by name is no problem at all. The code to sort the items and return a list is:

```
var sorted = MyList
    .OrderBy(item => item, new ArtikelTypeComparer())
    .ThenBy(item => item.Name)
    .ToList();
```

And you derive your `ArtikelTypeComparer` from is the generic [Comparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Because your type sort is not based on name, I created a lookup table that assigns the sorting order. And I added an "unknown" type so that if you add a new type and forget to update this comparer, the thing won't crash. Those new types will get sorted to the bottom.

```
public class ArtikelTypeComparer: Comparer<Artikel>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> NameSortOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"schoen", 0},
        {"broek", 1},
        {"shirt", 2},
        {"unknown", int.MaxValue}
    };

    public override int Compare(Artikel x, Artikel y)
    {
        if (x.ReferenceEquals(null) && y.ReferenceEquals(null)) return 0;
        if (x.ReferenceEquals(null)) return -1;
        if (y.ReferenceEquals(null)) return 1;

        int xOrder;
        int yOrder;
        if (!nameSortOrder.TryGetValue(x.GetType().Name), out xOrder))
        {
            xOrder = nameSortOrder["unknown"];
        }
        if (!nameSortOrder.TryGetValue(y.GetType().Name), out yOrder))
        {
            yOrder = nameSortOrder["unknown"];
        }

        return xSortOrder.CompareTo(ySortOrder);
}
```

If you're using `List.Sort` to sort the list (i.e. you want to sort it in place rather than create a new list), then you add the name comparison to the end of the comparer. Something like this:

```
public class ArtikelTypeAndNameComparer: Comparer<Artikel>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> NameSortOrder = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        {"schoen", 0},
        {"broek", 1},
        {"shirt", 2},
        {"unknown", int.MaxValue}
    };

    public override int Compare(Artikel x, Artikel y)
    {
        if (x.ReferenceEquals(null) && y.ReferenceEquals(null)) return 0;
        if (x.ReferenceEquals(null)) return -1;
        if (y.ReferenceEquals(null)) return 1;

        int xOrder;
        int yOrder;
        if (!nameSortOrder.TryGetValue(x.GetType().Name), out xOrder))
        {
            xOrder = nameSortOrder["unknown"];
        }
        if (!nameSortOrder.TryGetValue(y.GetType().Name), out yOrder))
        {
            yOrder = nameSortOrder["unknown"];
        }

        int rslt = xSortOrder.CompareTo(ySortOrder);
        if (rslt != 0)
        {
            return rslt;
        }

        // Types are the same. Compare names.
        return x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name);
}
```

And the code to do the sort is:

```
MyList.Sort(new ArtikelTypeAndNameComparer());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm still puzzled though. I can't seem to understand where the actual type sort happens. I have tested the solution and while debugging the xOrder and yOrder values never get altered. Please bear with me as I'm a C# noobie. I added the code I've used to test your solution in my OP.

Comment: @MCello: In the code, you need to change the keys in the dictionary (i.e. "schoen", "broek", etc.) with the actual type names. So if your "schoen" is actually defined as `public class Schoen: Artikel`, then change the string in the dictionary to "Schoen". In the debugger, see what is returned by `x.GetType().Name` and `y.GetType().Name`. Those are the names you want to use.

Comment: I overlooked the capital characters in the Dictionary section. Your solution works perfect now. Thanks,I learned something new!